# Процесс разработки приложения в docker

Tags: python, веб-программирование, docker

Разрабатывая приложения на python (микросервисы), в которых, помимо исходного кода, присутствует множество зависимостей в виде баз данных и т. д. - мы собираем докер-компоузы, при этом, насколько я понял, даже в процессе разработки лучше не выставлять порты наружу (что бы не было с коллизий с портами), а стучаться в сервисы-зависимости по их названию в compose.

А как тогда разрабатывать и дебажить?
До текущего момента я запускал приложения (запускал uvicorn в терминале vs code) локально и подключался к базам данных на localhost. А теперь, когда микросервисов стало много, напрашивается как-то вести разработку в докере? не могу понять как от этих localhost избавиться, что бы не приседать постоянно между процессами разработки/сборки

Comment: Поддержка разработки внутри контейнеров есть в VS Code. Более того, есть поддержка разработки в контейнере, который запущен из docker compose: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/containers/docker-compose

Comment: План Б: выдайте всем сервисам из `docker-compose.yml` статические IP адреса (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39493490) и присвойте в /etc/hosts каждому имени сервиса соответствующий адрес. Тогда при локальной разработке по этим именам ваш софт будет обращаться именно к тем контейнерам, которые нужны. В продакшене статические адреса удалите, а то может быть конфликт сетей.